# In KivyMD, How to add custom icons in Navigation Bar?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

This is my gui.py file

```
from kivymd.uix.navigationbar import MDNavigationItem, MDNavigationBar

class BaseMDNavigationItem(MDNavigationItem):
    source_icon = StringProperty()
    text = StringProperty()
```

and here is my gui.kv file

```
<BaseMDNavigationItem>
    MDNavigationItemLabel:
        text: root.text
    MDNavigationItemIcon:
        source: root.source_icon

MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDNavigationBar:
        on_switch_tabs: app.on_switch_tabs(*args)

        BaseMDNavigationItem:
            active: True
            text: "Screem1"

        BaseMDNavigationItem:
            text: "screen2"

        BaseMDNavigationItem:
            text: "screen3"
            source_icon: "path_to_file.jpg"
```

I tried MDicon but couldn't make it happen, so need help.
Also i removed other parts of the code, which seems not useful for the question.

Comment: The property under `MDNavigationItemIcon` should be `icon` and not `source`. See the [doc](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/navigation-bar/#example)

Comment: @Tranbi Yes it was like that before but still at that time, I could not load the custom icons which are in my icons folder.

Comment: The thing is that `MDNavigationItemIcon` inherits from `MDIcon` which inherits from `MDLabel`. Its content is therefore text and you cannot put a jpg inside. Checkout https://github.com/T-Dynamos/materialsymbols-python

Answer (score 0):

After looking into it, I found that you can use a `MDNavigationItemIconContainer` to put an image in it (with `FitImage`):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.navigationbar import MDNavigationBar, MDNavigationItem
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage


class BaseMDNavigationItem(MDNavigationItem):
    source_icon = StringProperty()
    text = StringProperty()


KV = '''
<BaseMDNavigationItem>
    MDNavigationItemIconContainer:
        size_hint_y: None
        FitImage:
            source: root.source_icon
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.3
            pos_hint: {"top": 0.8}
            fit_mode: "scale-down"
    MDNavigationItemLabel:
        text: root.text

MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    md_bg_color: self.theme_cls.backgroundColor

    MDScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        MDScreen:
            name: "Screen 1"
        MDScreen:
            name: "Screen 2"
        MDScreen:
            name: "Screen 3"

    MDNavigationBar:
        on_switch_tabs: app.on_switch_tabs(*args)

        BaseMDNavigationItem:
            active: True
            text: "Screen 1"
            source_icon: "thin.png"

        BaseMDNavigationItem:
            text: "Screen 2"
            source_icon: "chrome_icon_512.png"

        BaseMDNavigationItem:
            text: "Screen 3"
            source_icon: "./screenshot.png"

'''

class Example(MDApp):
    def on_switch_tabs(
        self,
        bar: MDNavigationBar,
        item: BaseMDNavigationItem,
        item_icon: str,
        item_text: str,
    ):
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = item_text

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Example().run()
```